# Activate searchView in android studio java

Tags: java, android-studio, searchview

I have a searchView in my form in android studio (JAVA) with below code:

```
<SearchView
        android:id="@+id/SView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
        android:background="#52BFECF4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvSearchDesc"/>
```

For type anything in this view, user should touch exactly the magnifier icon in searchView and if user touch anywhere else, the searchView dose not activate.

I need it to open always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```